# flatMap ignoring the result

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats

I was wondering if there exists a function (in scala or cats) which omits the result within `flatMap`. E.g.

```
Some("ignore this").ignoreArgumentFlatMap(Some("result"))
```

which would be the same as

```
Some("ignore this").flatMap(_ => Some("result"))
```

Comment: what would the use case be though?

Comment: I have some monads where the result is actually not of interest but only the inner state

Comment: e.g. `for { x <- someFoo; _ <- anotherFoo: _ <- moreOtherFoo; _ <- derp } yield x` - database transaction for example

Comment: hmmm... by the look of it, looks like anotherFoo, moreOtherFoo and derp are side-effecting things, right?

Comment: Yep, if one of them fail, they short circuit and the previous side effects are rolled back, in this my actual case (Doobie ConnectionIO)

Comment: would like to write it without for-comprehension as the result does not matter

Comment: not so sure this will help you but give a look at https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for

Comment: i think it does not solve my current problem, but its an interesting project, did no know about this, might be usefull for other parts of my project, thanks

Comment: In your case, isn't it rather `Some("result").flatMap(x => { Some("ignore this"); Some(x) })` (to have the equivalent of your for-comprehension)?

Comment: in the case of option this is correct, but there are monads for which commands in the sequence do not commute due to internal state

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called `>>` in cats.

```
scala> import cats.implicits._
import cats.implicits._

scala> Option("ignore this") >> Some("result")
res14: Option[String] = Some(result)
```

The documentation explicitly says

> Alias for fa.flatMap(_ => fb).
>
> Unlike *>, fb is defined as a by-name parameter, allowing this method to be used in cases where computing fb is not stack safe unless suspended in a flatMap.

There's also `productR` or `*>`.

```
scala> Option("ignore this").productR(Some("result"))
res15: Option[String] = Some(result)

scala> Option("ignore this") *> Some("result")
res16: Option[String] = Some(result)
```

Like the doc said its argument is not by-name though. So it's more or less equivalent to

```
val x0 = Some("result")
Some("ignore this").flatMap(_ => x0)
```

There's `productREval` if you want an alternative evaluation strategy.

Comment: is there also an analogue for "map"? e.g. `x.ignoreMap(someValue)` would be  `x.map(_ => someValue)`?

Comment: @keksnicoh I think that's `x.as(someValue)` but again it's not by-name.